# Jquery: Replace image source getting link from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a help and I am stuck how to replace a image source by getting the url link from its anchor tag.
And I need to repeat this for a n number of div.

What I have is n number of div, and a anchor tag in each div with a image.
When someone hover on a image tag, the source of image should changed by getting the source from anchor tag and I also want to disable the anchor click. Is this possible?

Have a look at the code:

```
<div class="slide" data-type="image">
        <a href="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Audi-A1.jpg">
            <img data-image="http://earnthis.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Toy-Story-2-Disney-Wallpaper-Picture.jpg" 
            data-src="http://earnthis.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Toy-Story-2-Disney-Wallpaper-Picture.jpg" 
        src="http://earnthis.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Toy-Story-2-Disney-Wallpaper-Picture.jpg"
            />
        </a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7AqkS/1/

Thanks, I am not good in jquery :(

Comment: Why do you have a link that can't, or shouldn't, be activated?

Comment: Maybe he want to open some sort of menu on hover/click. Otherwise I don't get it.

Comment: I need to change a image on a div and I am restricted to pass any custom attribute to image tag.. but I can add anchor tag.. so I choose this method.. If I need to open the image in full screen then I can remove the preventDefault() later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve basic rollover effect with this code:

```
$(".slide a").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').prop('src', this.href);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('img').prop('src', function() {
        return $(this).data('src');
    });
})
.on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7AqkS/6/

Or if you want something fancier:

```
$('.slide a').on({
     'mouseover mouseout': function(e) {
         $('img', this).prop('src', function() {
             return e.type == 'mouseover' ? e.delegateTarget.href : $(this).data('src');
         });
     },
     click: function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     }
 });
```

Comment: +1 and for the second part of question $(".slide a").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();});

Comment: @MiljanPuzović You are right, missed that part. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need a little more improvement..
there would be a value in img tag.. like data-image-resolution="500w"
i need to grab its value and merge in old source with url + ? + 5oow.
Do you get it? It will not add in the anchor tag link but it will add in img source which will be replaced when the cursor is leaved.

Comment: And one more request, can you explain your code for my understanding?
I did not get how you are grabbing the anchor link which I have put.

Comment: `this.href` this is an anchor tag href attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the parents 'href' attribute and set the images 'src' attribute to its value, like this.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

     // One way che
     $( ".slide img" ).hover( function( element ){
         var image = $( this );
         var newImage = image.parent( 'a' ).attr( 'href' );
         image.attr( 'src', newImage );

     });

     // Prevent Default anchor behavior
     $( ".slide a" ).click( function(element){ 
          element.preventDefault();
          element.stopPropagation();
     });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you http://jsfiddle.net/7AqkS/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="slide" data-type="image"> <a href="http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/08/30/49859/Google+steel.png?t=20110830212412">
        <img data-image="http://www.technewspaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/google1.jpg" 
                data-src="http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/08/30/49859/Google+steel.png?t=20110830212412" 
            src="http://www.technewspaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/google1.jpg"/>
    </a>

</div>
<div class="slide" data-type="image">
    <a href="http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/08/30/49859/Google+steel.png?t=20110830212412">
                <img data-image="http://www.technewspaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/google1.jpg" 
                data-src="http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/08/30/49859/Google+steel.png?t=20110830212412" 
            src="http://www.technewspaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/google1.jpg"/>
    </a>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".slide img").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("image"));
});
});
```